# Can only use .dt accessor with datetimelike values

Tags: python, datetime

When i trying to convert the string to datetime, I am facing some issues.

```
testdata['pe']
Out[69]: 
0     2019-09-26
1     2019-10-31
2     2019-08-28
3     2019-06-20
4     2019-09-30
5     2019-07-22
6     2019-07-31
7     2019-08-30
8     2019-07-29
9     2019-06-28
10    2019-11-20
Name: prd_exp_dt, dtype: object
```

When i did, `testdata.pe=testdata.pe.dt.strftime('%Y%M')`, i get this error:

```
Can only use .dt accessor with datetimelike values
```

Tried to do errors:"corerce", like this:

```
pandas.to_datetime(testdata['prd_exp_dt'],errors = 'coerce',format = '%Y%M')
Out[68]: 
0    NaT
1    NaT
2    NaT
3    NaT
4    NaT
5    NaT
6    NaT
7    NaT
8    NaT
9    NaT
10   NaT
Name: prd_exp_dt, dtype: datetime64[ns]
```

Need some guidance on this.

Comment: `pandas.to_datetime(testdata['pe'] ,errors = 'coerce',format = '%Y-%m-%d')` ?

Comment: i need to change to this format: format = '%Y%M'

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Use format `'%Y-%m-%d'` and use `.dt.strftime("%Y%m")`

**Ex:**

```
import pandas as pd
testdata['prd_exp_dt'] = pd.to_datetime(testdata['prd_exp_dt'] ,errors = 'coerce',format = '%Y-%m-%d').dt.strftime("%Y%m")
```